# Using unsigned char and char

Tags: c

I looked at many implementations of strCmp() and found that most of the pointers implementations are done using unsigned char

My question is why "unsigned" used in return even though if we didn't use it we will get the same result (based on the tests I did)?

if I didn't use it, will I get a wrong result for some values?

Lastly, is char unsigned or signed by default?

Example 1

```
int strCmp(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    while(*s1 && (*s1 == *s2))
    {
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }    
    return *(const unsigned char*)s1 - *(const unsigned char*)s2;
}
```

Example 2

```
int strCmp(const char *S1, const char *S2)
{

  for(; *S1 == *S2; ++S1, ++S2)
    if(*S1 == 0)
      return 0;
  return *(unsigned char *)S1 < *(unsigned char *)S2 ? -1 : 1;
  }
```

Comment: Whether char is signed or unsigned is not standardized and left to the implementation.  Often unsigned by default in older compilers, today compilers usually have an option to change it.  That won't do for the return value of strcmp(), you are seeing the library implementer picking a predictable value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My question is why "unsigned" used in return even though if we didn't use it we will get the same result (based on the tests I did)?

Arithmetics are done with the type `int`, so **if** `char` is signed, you will get wrong values for negative chars because of sign extending them.

Example: assume your chars are 8 bits wide and signed with 2's complement. Then the character at code point 128 would have an integer value of `-128` and therefore compare *smaller* than any in the range [0,127], not what you want. Casting to `unsigned char` first makes sure the integer value is `128`.

> Lastly, is char unsigned or signed by default?

This is, in fact, *implementation defined*. So, explicitly use *unsigned char* to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

> I looked at many implementations of strCmp() and found that most of the pointers implementations are done using unsigned char

Code that implements the standard C library function `int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);` is **specified** to perform the comparison as if the string was composed of `unsigned char` characters.  This applies if `char` is implemented as `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char`  C11 §7.24.1 3

```
// Example that performs the correct compare without a possibility of overflow.
int strCmp(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
  const unsigned char *u1 = (const unsigned char *) s1;
  const unsigned char *u2 = (const unsigned char *) s2;
  while((*u1 == *u2) && *u1) {
    u1++;
    u2++;
  }    
  return (*u1 > *u2) - (*u1 < *u2);
}
```

---

Below fails on rare machines where range of `unsigned char` == range of `unsigned`.

```
return *(const unsigned char*)s1 - *(const unsigned char*)s2;
```